# Laravel: WhereIn not pulling any values

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a *small* little side project where users can upload videos/share videos. I have this feature called **tags**, wherein the upload screen, you can select what tags your video falls under (Kind of like YouTube). This works fine for the most part, except for one thing. On this website, you can browse by video tags. So if you click on a "Movie" tag, you get sent to the webpage that shows you all the videos with the "Movie" tag.

**What it looks like**

[image: What the feature looks like]

The way I'm doing this right now is using a simple Where In statement. In my database, I have a table specifically for videos, and one of the columns is all the tag id's you selected for your video in json format. Once you click a specific tag, it will get all the videos where the video tags match up with the tag id you clicked on. But when I try to click on the tag, it returns nothing.

**Controller code**

```
public function browse($name) //(This is the name of the tag from web route)
{
    $tag = Tag::wheretag($name)->first();
    
    if ($tag){
    $tagi = array($tag->id);
    $uploads = Video::whereIn('tags', $tagi)->paginate(10);
    return view('browse')->with('uploads', $uploads)->with('name', $name)
    }else{
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'That tag does not exists');
    }
}
```

**The web route**

```
Route::get('/browse/{name}', 'Controller@browse')->name('Browse');
```

For some reason this has stumped me, even though I think it should be easy to pull off. If there is any other way to do this, please tell!
Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: That's because tags is a json column. WhereIn doesnt work with json. You need JSON CONTAINS to query that column. Laravel has `whereJsonContains` I believe.

Comment: Why not use a relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd setup a tags-table and a tag_video pivot table. Then give both video and tags a belongsToMany relation to eachother.
[Documentation on many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

This way you can query the videos on the tag-relation:
`$videos = Tag::find(1)->videos`

This will improve readability, and make it far easier for you to manage tags on a video - and conform with normalization of your database.

Comment: Thank you! This seems more obvious to me now that I'm thinking about it, but It's also 4 am so I may just be too tired lol. This has fixed my issue, thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

> I have a table specifically for videos, and one of the columns is all the tag id's you selected for your video in json format.

WhereIn will not work with json fields. To query json fields you need `whereJsonContains`.

```
$uploads = Video::whereJsonContains('tags', $tagi)->paginate(10);
```